# Como configurar o apache para ignorar o diretório na url?

Tags: url, rotas, apache

Tenho um diretório dentro de minha pasta raiz chamado "mydir" onde existem vários arquivos, atualmente eu acesso esses arquivos assim:

http://mysite.com/mydir/myarchive.html

Minha dúvida é tenho como configurar o .htaccess para que eu posso acessa(mostrar ára o usuário) esses arquivos assim:

http://mysite.com/myarchive.html

Porém não quero redirecionar todos os arquivos, apenas os ".html".

Estou tentando em meu .htaccess, porém recebo um 404:

```
RewriteRule "^/(.+)$" "/mydir/$1"
```

Onde "^/(.+)$" é a expressão regular, que pelo que li na documentação do [apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/pt-br/rewrite/intro.html) quer dizer:

**^** = âncora para iniciar a expressão.

**/** = raiz do projeto.

**(.)** = significa qualquer caractere.

**+** = repetir o "." uma ou mais vezes.

**/mydir/** = diretório qual eu quero substituir.

**$1** = variável referente a expressão regular entre parênteses.

**$** = âncora para finalizar a expressão.

E mesmo assim, quando tento acessar http://mysite.com/myarchive.html, eu recebo um erro 404 de página não encontrada. Veja que nem fiz ainda pegar apenas o html, mas imagino que seria algo assim "^/(..html)$" onde é preciso escapar o . com um barra invertida.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que seja algo assim:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(.*)/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} /.+\.html$
RewriteRule (.+) /mydir/$1 [QSA, L]
```

Essa condição pega qualquer arquivo `.html` na raiz e reescreve a URL para `/mydir/arquivo.html`

Comment: Mas a questão é exatamente o contrário, estou precisando de pegar todos de "mydir" e poder acessar assim http://mysite.com/myarchive.html ao invés de http://mysite.com/mydir/myarchive.html, mas já ajuda, irei ver aqui.

Comment: Erro interno do Servidor! 500, está dando erro na sintaxe desta linha aqui `RewriteRule (.+) /mydir/$1 [QSA, L]`

Answer (score 0):

Depois de horas tentando eu consegui. É só fazer assim no seu .htaccess, irei explicar:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/mydir/
RewriteRule "^(.+\.html)$" "/mydir/$1"
```

**RewriteEngine On**

Ativa o modo de reescrita.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/mydir/
```

Para criar uma condição e negar "`/mydir/`" no loop, se não aconteceria algo como: `/mydir/mydir/mydir/mydir/mydir/mydir/mydir/mydir/mydir/mydir/`

```
RewriteRule "^(.+\.html)$" "/mydir/$1"
```

E por ultimo a regra de reescrita, onde "^(.+.html)$" é a expressão regular que quer dizer que irá pegar todos os arquivos .html, perceba a necessidade de escapar o ponto, pois o mesmo é um caractere de expressão regular que significa "qualquer caractere", o + é para repetir o ponto uma ou mais vezes.